# ArcGIS JS API RasterShaderReliefRenderer does not color full range of DEM elevation values

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dem, interpolation, imagery, color-ramp

I have a DEM of the state of florida as an ImageService, [here](https://ca.dep.state.fl.us/arcgis/rest/services/Imagery/USGS_NationalMap_10m_DEM/ImageServer).  I want to render this DEM using nicer colors than black and white using the ArcGIS JS API.  Following the example [ImageryTileLayer - shaded relief renderer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/layers-imagery-renderer/)
, I apply a RasterShadedReliefRender as the imagelayer's renderer:

```js
import RasterShadedReliefRenderer from "@arcgis/core/renderers/RasterShadedReliefRenderer";
import AlgorithmicColorRamp from "@arcgis/core/rest/support/AlgorithmicColorRamp.js";
import Color from "@arcgis/core/Color.js";
import MultipartColorRamp from "@arcgis/core/rest/support/MultipartColorRamp.js";

const renderer = new RasterShadedReliefRenderer({
  hillshadeType: "traditional",
  zFactor: 15,
  scalingType: "adjusted",
  colorRamp: new MultipartColorRamp({
    colorRamps: [
      new AlgorithmicColorRamp({
        fromColor: new Color("#2F86A6"),
        toColor: new Color("#12372A"),
      }),
    ],
  }),
});


const layer = new ImageryLayer({
  url: the_url_from_above,
  renderer
})
```

This is working, except the range of colors from the color ramp doesn't seem to span the full range of elevations in the layer.  The resulting image:

[image]

You can see there is a nice gradient right around the sea level, but above that, the hillshade seems to be colored on more of a greyscale.

I tried adding more ramps within the colorRamp, but the same problem occurs.  For example

```js
export const renderer = new RasterShadedReliefRenderer({
  hillshadeType: "traditional",
  zFactor: 15,
  scalingType: "adjusted",
  colorRamp: new MultipartColorRamp({
    colorRamps: [
      new AlgorithmicColorRamp({
        fromColor: new Color("#2F86A6"),
        toColor: new Color("#12372A"),
      }),
      new AlgorithmicColorRamp({
        fromColor: new Color("#12372A"),
        toColor: new Color("#436850"),
      }),
      new AlgorithmicColorRamp({
        fromColor: new Color("#436850"),
        toColor: new Color("#ADBC9F"),
      }),
    ],
  }),
});
```

This results in:

[image]

To make the point stupidly obviously, with more ridiculous colors added in there, I get results like these:

[image]
[image]

You can see that adding more color ramps just compresses the colors into the same range.  While the colors are darker in the last images, you can see there is still more terrain being represented by a darkening of the last color.

The goal here is that the start of the color ramp should take the lowest value in the DEM, and the end of it should take the highest value in the DEM.  That doesn't seem to be happening here.

What I doing wrong?  How can I create a continuous color ramp that continuously belnds from the `fromColor` to the `toColor` across the range of values in the DEM ImageryLayer?

#### Edit: A working layer

I notice that when I try an [alternative but older DEM](https://ca.dep.state.fl.us/arcgis/rest/services/Imagery/Digital_Elevation_Model_2009/ImageServer), I get the desired result:

[image]

The difference that I see is that this older DEM is just of florida, and  has a min and max value listed of 0-336 - the elevations in m within the state of Florida.  And the serviceDataType is `esriImageServiceDataTypeGeneric`.  Whereas the one that is not working, the min and max values are listed as `-0.7808904001722112` and `13.772270436049439`, and the Service Data Type is `esriImageServiceDataTypeElevation`.  I don't quite understand this second one - why is the range of min and max values so small?  What units is it in?   How does `esriImageServiceDataTypeGeneric` differ from `esriImageServiceDataTypeElevation`, and how does that affect my  shaded relief renderer?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a solution, just some findings that show there might be something wrong with the way that `RasterShadedReliefRenderer` interprets `ImageryLayer`.

If in `ImageryLayer` creation instead of specifying `renderer` option `pixelFilter` is used and in the filer function min and max values are checked, these are the value:

```
min: -1.695206642150879
max: 182.93194580078125
```

This shows that there are values over `13.772270436049439`, but are all presented with the same color.

This code:

```
function maskPixels(pixelData) {
  const minVal = pixelData.pixelBlock.statistics[0].minValue;
  const maxVal = pixelData.pixelBlock.statistics[0].maxValue;
  console.log(minVal, maxVal);
}

const layer = new ImageryLayer({
  url,
  pixelFilter: maskPixels
});
```

gives the following image:

[image]

This shows that obviously there is full range of heights, it's just that `RasterShadedReliefRenderer` does not interpret them correctly. I tried all the color ramps like in this example https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/layers-imagery-renderer/, but all had the same problem.

Comment: Interestingly, applying a rasterFunction of `rasterFunctionUtils.grayscale` seems to achieve exactly the same result as what you have above.  If I *then* apply the `RasterShadedReliefRenderer`, it gives the desired result.  Maybe I'll post an answer with these findings as well.  Sort of unrelated question - would it be possible to use the pixelFilter to make all pixel values less than 0 transparent, to create a sort of faux-mask of the state according to sea level?

Comment: I'm trying to use `rasterFunction: rasterFunctionUtils.grayscale` option, but I'm getting this error in browser console: `Uncaught TypeError: g.includes is not a function`

Comment: Greyscale was added in 4.29, which was released *really* recently - not sure if that has an affect on your setup

Comment: As a last resort I had a look at the docs :-) and realized it has to be: `rasterFunctionUtils.grayscale({weights: [1]})`.

Comment: Masking is possible in `pixelFilter` function, but when this option is used, `renderer` is ignored.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer, it could be useful to somebody. It's hard to find solutions in comments.

Comment: You could use `rasterFunctionUtils.remap` raster function for setting desired pixels to no data value.